# \edef with accent breaks List of Tables

Tags: tex-core, unicode, input-encodings, auxiliary-files

Foreword: I'm aware that I'm doing unusual stuff with LaTeX `:P`

I noticed that when I use `\edef` in something that contains an unicode (non-ASCII) character, TeX not only expands the macros, but also expands said unicode character (an `ó`, for example).

I also learned that LaTeX does some [trickery](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31640/what-is-the-use-of-the-command-iec) with these characters when writing the auxiliary files.

But these two facts don't add up `Ç_Ç`.

For example, the following code will throw an error when compiled for the second time to add the `\listoftables`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\edef\WeirdWayOfInsertingACaption{Fósforo}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
 \caption{\WeirdWayOfInsertingACaption}
 \begin{tabular}{cccc}
  Can & I & Haz & LOT?
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It will break beacuse `\edef` somehow expands the `ó` in such a way that LaTeX fails to spot it and write the `\IeC{\'o}` to the `.toc` file. Instead it writes a plain `ó`, and when the `\listoftables` command tries to write the List of Tables, we get this error:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �sfo (U+14B)
>
> (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Is it possible to make the above code work keeping the `\edef`?

Comment: This is exactly why `\edef` isn't supported in latex unless you have complete control over the input, for general latex tokens you need `\protected@edef`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Didn't know about `\protected@edef`. Thanks a lot!