# Efficiently setting category code for a range of characters

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, programming, cyrillic, catcodes

I kept thinking about [using Cyrillic characters in command names with PDFTeX engine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439543).  It looks to me so far that if I stay with 8-bit encoding and assign category code 11 to all Cyrillic letters except `ё`/`Ё`, this would be a working solution, except that bookmarks created with `hyperref` will be misencoded.

A workaround to fix PDF bookmarks created with `hyperref` would be to temporarily set category codes back to 13 for sectioning commands, and to not use commands with Cyrillic letters inside sectioning commands, or to use `\texorpdfstring`, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\catcode`л=11\relax
\catcode`п=11\relax
\catcode`к=11\relax

\newcommand{\лк}{«}
\newcommand{\пк}{»}

\begin{document}

{\catcode`л=13\relax
\section{Раздел «Первый»}}

{\catcode`л=13\relax
\gdef\pdfbookmarkname{Раздел «Второй»}}
\section{\texorpdfstring{Раздел \лк Второй\пк}{\pdfbookmarkname}}

\end{document}
```

This document, when compiled, has properly encoded bookmarks.

What would be an efficient way to set category code for the whole range of Cyrillic letters, except `ё`/`Ё`?

Comment: do not set category codes in that way you will break latex's encoding support completely, use UTF-8 inputencoding then you can input latin and cyrillic without changing encoding

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, i cannot use Cyrillic letters in command names with UTF-8 encoding and PDFTeX engine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, what will this break in addition to `hyperref`?

Comment: the price you pay for an 8-bit system.  If you need more why not use luatex or xetex which are set up for unicode characters.  making things catcode 11 just works for some undocumented subset of T2A that happens to be the same as cp1251 and will work in some simple cases, but really breaks core latex mechanisms

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, my question is specifically about PDFTeX engine, XeTeX is [unavailable](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#other_formats).  I am trying to find a least intrusive solution to fix  PDF bookmarks in a third-party document encoded Windows-1251 and using [`russlh`](https://www.mccme.ru/free-books/p_cher.htm#engl) package.

Comment: If you really need to do this I guess you know what to do, there isn't really any special efficient thing to do just make the 128 high bit characters catcode 11 or 13, but in 99% of cases it would be better to use utf-8 and ascii command names.

Comment: I am not particularly good at (La)TeX programming.

Comment: Drop the idea. While it can be neat to define commands in your own language, the price you pay is too high. And what will you do if after an upload you get asked to deliver an utf8-encoded document as utf8 is the standard now?